# jQuery .on('click') vs. .click() and .delegate('click')

Tags: jquery

I'm used to using `.click()` and `delegate('click')`, so when I read both were deprecated in recent versions of jQuery I thought I'd read up on it, but I'm scratching my head a bit.

The documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) seems to suggest that this is a drop-in replacement for [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), but [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) had a different behavior, namely binding to currently existing objects, where the others bound to any objects that matched the selector pattern througout the lifespan of the DOM.

In most cases, this wouldn't make a big difference, but when adding elements to your DOM dynamically, this is an important distinction.  New objects matching the old pattern would *not* have listeners tied to the `click` event using `.click()`, but *would* with `.delegate()`.

My question is, how does one use the `.on()` method to duplicate the behavior of both the pre-existing `.delegate()` and `.bind()`?  Or is everything in the future going towards the `.delegate()` style?

Comment: Read the [documention](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for `click()`.  **It's not deprecated.**  _"...this method is a **shortcut** for ... `.on("click", handler)` as of jQuery 1.7."_

Comment: ...ok, allow me to rephrase: it is repurposed.  It used to be a shortcut for `.bind()`, and now it's not.

Comment: It's now a shortcut for `.on()`, which has replaced `.bind()` for binding events to existing elements. It's also replaced `.delegate()` for event delegation on static (non-document) elements, and `.live()` for event delegation on the entire document.

Comment: Just use .on() and you're doing well

Comment: Quote OP: _"My question is, how does one use the .on() method to duplicate the behavior of both the pre-existing `.delegate()` and `.bind()`?"_ ~  I'm curious if you saw the extensive explanations in [the documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: Also, as a semi-random aside, event delegation is generally preferable to binding events to individual elements. If you have, for example, 100 elements with a given class and you called `$('.yourclass').click(...);` you'd end up binding 100 click event handlers. With event delegation, you only have a single event handler bound, which will handle the clicks for all 100 elements. So, even if you're not dynamically adding elements, depending on the number of elements being affected, delegation is probably the better choice.

Comment: @Sparky672, my problem was that the documentation seemed to go into some detail about direct or delegated behavior, which *seemed* to be talking about `bind()` and `delegate()`, respectively, but didn't seem to say it.  It left me confused, and inspired this question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: That depends on what kind of events you handle, and how many. If you have 100 events that are completely unrelated, it's more efficient to handle them on the element directly, instead of letting all events pass through a single handler that has to go through all 100 selectors to figure out what event goes to what handler.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Both modes are still supported.

The following call to `bind()`:

```
$(".foo").bind("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Can be directly converted into the following call to `on()`:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

And the following call to `delegate()`:

```
$("#ancestor").delegate(".foo", "click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Can be converted into the following call to `on()`:

```
$("#ancestor").on("click", ".foo", function() {
    // ...
});
```

For completeness, the following call to `live()`:

```
$(".foo").live("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Can be converted into the following call to `on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".foo", function() {
    // ...
});
```

---

### UPDATE:

Except `on` event, the rest of the events were deprecated in different jQuery versions.

- `bind` -  version deprecated: 3.0
- `live` -  version  deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9
- `delegate` - version deprecated: 3.0

Comment: Excellent.  This is what I suspected, but the documentation was not clear to me.  Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly it seems that delegate is much much faster than the others: http://jsperf.com/on-vs-bind-vs-delegate-vs-native, update with delegated on(), as fast as delegate...

Comment: With `delegate()` If i remove ".foo" element and later i add again ".foo" the initial bind persists. with `on()` this behavior is the same? im trying on jquery 2.2.4 and seems to remove the bind.

Comment: @ontananza, depends on the form of `on()` you're using. If you're using the binding form and the matching element is removed, the event won't be handled indeed. If you're using the delegated form and the ancestor is removed, the event won't be handled indeed either. You have to understand what's going on under the hood in order to use `on()` appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

The `on` method can replace both `bind` and `delegate` depending on how it's used (and also `click` as `bind` can replace that):

```
.click(handler) == .on('click', handler)

.bind('click', handler) ==  .on('click', handler)

.delegate('click', '#id', handler) == .on('click', '#id', handler)
```

Neither the `click`, `delegate` or `bind` methods have made it to the [deprecated page](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) yet. I doubt that the `click` method ever will.

Answer (score 2):

You can deduce the usage for the aliases from the source code.

```
console.log($.fn.delegate);
function (a, b, c, d) {
    return this.on(b, a, c, d);
}

console.log($.fn.bind);
function (a, b, c) {
    return this.on(a, null, b, c);
}
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) also provides the usage examples:

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.delegate()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L954) and [`.bind()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L970) uses `on` method. And `.click()` is a [shortcut](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L1020) for `.on()` too.