# Reload captcha image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I have a php script which generates a png image with a captcha code as image text.

```
session_start();   
$captchanumber = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; 
$captchanumber = substr(str_shuffle($captchanumber), 0, 8); 
$_SESSION["code"] = $captchanumber; 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("cap.jpg");     
$black  = imagecolorallocate($image, 160, 160, 160);   
$font = '../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf';  
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 35, 27, $black, $font, $captchanumber);   
header('Content-type: image/png');    
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

I want to reload the image via jQuery or JavaScript,so i'm using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.captcha').click(function(){
        alert('yolo');
        var id = Math.random();
        $(".captcha").replaceWith('<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php?id='+id+'" />');
        id ='';

    });
});
```

the field:

```
<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php">
```

As the first attempt,it works , but after that if i click on the field again it won't work anymore and i have no idea why .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are replacing the dom element with new element, it will destroy all attached event handlers.

**Method 1:** You can resolve this by using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to listen dynamically added elements event.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('body').on('click', '.captcha', function(){
        alert('yolo');
        var id = Math.random();
        $(this).replaceWith('<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php?id='+id+'" />');
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('body').on('click', '.captcha', function() {
    alert('yolo');
    var id = Math.random();
    $(this).replaceWith('<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php?id=' + id + '" />');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php">
```

---

**Method 2:** Instead of replacing entire element just update the img src attribute with new url.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.captcha').click(function(){
        alert('yolo');
        var id = Math.random();
        $(this).attr('src', 'img/captcha.php?id='+id);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.captcha').click(function() {
    alert('yolo');
    var id = Math.random();
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/captcha.php?id=' + id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php">
```

---

**Method 3:** Also you can get it done with pure JavaScript with same logic as previous.

```js
document.querySelector('.captcha').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('yolo');
  var id = Math.random();
  this.setAttribute('src', 'img/captcha.php?id=' + id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php">
```

---

**Method 4:** Setting **[`onClick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes)** attribute to the element and handling the click event with pure JavaScript, where you need to pass `this` as argument to refer the element.

```js
function captcha(ele) {
  alert('yolo');
  var id = Math.random();
  ele.setAttribute('src', 'img/captcha.php?id=' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="captcha" onclick="captcha(this)" src="img/captcha.php">
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason your code only works once is because the original element with captcha class is [replaced and the click is no longer detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements).

*Solution*

A clean solution would be to replace the src of the image instead of the complete element.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4351/)

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#changeThis").click(
            function () {
                changeImage();
            }            
        );
    });

function changeImage() {
   //we want whole numbers not numbers with dots here for cleaner urls
   var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
   $('#changeThis').attr("src",'img/captcha.php?id='+id);
   //Not sure why you want to empty id though.
   id ='';
}
```

Or in oneline:

```
$("#changeThis").click($('#changeThis').attr("src",'img/captcha.php?id='+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)));
```

**HTML** For unique elements use the id="" syntax instead of class="", class is used when multiple elements can have the same class, id is an identifier for a unique element.

```
<img class="captcha" id="changeThis" src="img/captcha.php">
```

Answer (score 3):

Might just be a problem with binding events to elements that your code replaces. Consider [delegate binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296530/jquery-onclick-vs-click-and-delegateclick) to the document instead:

```
// Replace
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.captcha').click(function(){
// With
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.captcha').on('click', document, function(){
```

Comment: Based on the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/on/, you should write: $(document).on('click', '.captcha', function() { ... } ). The element that is added later to the document is passed as 2nd argument, not vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The problem is that you declare the `id` variable, and you try to redeclare it in the second function call, when there already is an `id` variable, so it will silently be ignored and the empty string used instead.

Try moving `var id ='';` out of the function, and use `id = Math.random()` in the function.

Comment: The problem is he replaces the complete element which has a direct binding, by replacing it the binding with the function isnt valid anymore, a delegated binding would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a delegation issue, as you have inserted a new element, so the event listener is removed, there are many solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Use inline event binding

```
function rebindCaptcha()
{
var id = Math.random();
        $(".captcha").replaceWith('<img onclick="rebindCaptcha()" class="captcha" src="img/captcha.php?id='+id+'" />');
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Keep your element in dom, and just change the src attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('.captcha').click(function(){
          var id = Math.random();
          this.src = 'img/captcha.php?id='+id+';
          id ='';

      });
  });
```

Just for your reference, jQuery delegation can be done with like:

```
$(".parent .child").on("event",function(){/*your handler here*/})
```

or

```
$(".parent").on("event",".child",function(){/*your handler here*/})
```

Usually pick a parent that you are sure it will always exist in your dom, and always attach listener after document ready event.

Answer (score 0):

For me its working as i say you have to use id in javascript for changing things

```
// reload is your button reload and captcha must be a div who surrounding the captcha img

document.querySelector('#reload').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var reload = document.getElementById('captcha')
  reload.innerHTML = "your new logic"
})
```

//reload.innerHTML gonna be the new captcha html code

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the image with new code, you can use version paramter for captcha.php. See the following code.

```
<img class="captcha" id="secure_code" src="img/captcha.php"> <a href="#" id="reload_captcha">Reload</a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#relaod_captcha').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault() ;
        $('#secure_code').attr('src', "img/captcha.php?ver="+Math.random()) ;
    }) ;
}) ;
```

I wish it will help.