# JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.mousedown() event shorthand is deprecated and more deprecations

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

i'm ugrading jQuery to version 3.6.0 in a project using jQuery qtip 3.0.3 (released on 11 May 2016).
Also i'm using jQuery migrate 3.3.2, which is returning some deprecated functions of qtip, as qtip is [not maintained](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2) anymore i want to change the mentioned methods by myself.

This is the qtip library i'm using: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.js

The first deprecation message looks like:

> ```
> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.mousedown() event shorthand is deprecated
> migrateWarn @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:100
> jQuery.fn.<computed> @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:682
> S.fn.init @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> jQuery.fn.init @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:158
> S @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> init @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2724
> OVERLAY @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2833
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2835
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:25
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:28
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:3487
> jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:102 console.trace
> ```

The second deprecation message looks like:

> ```
> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.delegate() is deprecated
> migrateWarn @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:100
> delegate @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:713
> delegate @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:1400
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:1672
> e @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> t @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> setTimeout (async)
> (anonymous) @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> c @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> fire @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> c @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> fireWith @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> ready @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> B @ jquery_3_6_0_min_1.js:2
> jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:102 console.trace
> ```

The third deprecation message looks like:

> ```
> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.bind() is deprecated
> migrateWarn @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:100
> bind @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:705
> init @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2732
> OVERLAY @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2833
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2835
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:25
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:28
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:3487
> jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:102 console.trace
> migrateWarn @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:102
> bind @ jquery_migrate_3_3_2.js:705
> init @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2732
> OVERLAY @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2833
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:2835
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:25
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:28
> (anonymous) @ jquery_qtip_3_0_3.js:3487
> ```

The messages are regarding e.g.

> ```
>    elem = self.elem = $('<div />', {          
>       id: 'qtip-overlay',             
>       html: '<div></div>',            
>       mousedown: function() { return FALSE; }         
>    })
>   .hide();
> ```

> ```
> function delegate(selector, events, method) {
>   $(document.body).delegate(selector,
>       (events.split ? events : events.join('.'+NAMESPACE + ' ')) + '.'+NAMESPACE,
>       function() {
>           var api = QTIP.api[ $.attr(this, ATTR_ID) ];
>           api && !api.disabled && method.apply(api, arguments);
>       }
>   );
> }
> ```

and

> ```
> $(document.body).bind('focusin'+MODALSELECTOR, stealFocus);
> $(document).bind('keydown'+MODALSELECTOR, function(event) {
> elem.bind('click'+MODALSELECTOR, function(event) {
> ```

Now i wonder how to replace them correctly with the `on` event. With `bind` i suppose, i can easily replace it with `.on`, but how to process with mousedown and delegate?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Related: [jQuery .on('click') vs. .click() and .delegate('click')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296530/jquery-onclick-vs-click-and-delegateclick)

Comment: `.delegate(selector, event, func)` -> `.on(event, selector, func)`.   `.bind(event, func)` -> `.on(event, func)`   `.mousedown` (not deprecated according to [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)) -> `.on("mousedown", func)`

Comment: Hey @freedomn-m, thanks a lot! It was working with almost all of them, i'm right now just not sure about the mousedown as it looks like this:

`mousedown: function() { return FALSE; }`


Is the following part correct?:

`on("mousedown", function() { return FALSE; })`

Comment: So far `on: ('mousedown', function() { return FALSE; })` is not giving any error message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could solve it with the answer from freedomn-m :)

Solution:

```
elem = self.elem = $('<div />', {
        id: 'qtip-overlay',
        html: '<div></div>',
        on: ('mousedown', function() { return FALSE; })
        })
        .hide();


function delegate(events, selector, method) {
    $(document.body).on(events.split ? events : events.join('.'+NAMESPACE + ' ')) + '.'+NAMESPACE,
        (selector,
        function() {
            var api = QTIP.api[ $.attr(this, ATTR_ID) ];
            api && !api.disabled && method.apply(api, arguments);
        }
    );
}

$(document.body).on('focusin'+MODALSELECTOR, stealFocus);
```